# For loop executing only one iteration

Tags: java, shapes, println

I am trying to use a for statement to print some slashes three times. When I run the program, it simply prints once when I want it to print three times.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.out.println("+----+");       
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++); {
        System.out.println("\\    /");
        System.out.println("/    \\");
    }
    System.out.println("+----+");
}
```

It prints:

```
               +----+
               \    /
               /    \
               +----+
```

Comment: You've posted a requirement and an attempt, but no question.

Comment: True haha, I'll make any other questions clearer. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++);`

This is a for loop that does nothing.
Anything that follows is not part of the loop, and therefore is only executed once.

remove the `;`

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++);
```

should instead be:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
```